# How to Post Image on Google+ with Android Application

Tags: android, google-plus

i have integrated google+ with android. but i am not able to post image over there. on google api docs **ShareCompat** class is used for that. but it is found in api level 16.

plz Help..!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the Android Support Library in order to use the ShareCompat class in API level 4 and higher.

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#SettingUp